# How to add Comment on linkedin company page feeds using api

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I'm new to working with Linkedin API.

I'm trying to add a comment on the company page feeds using API curl.

Here is my code.

```
$params1 = array(
    "endpoint"  => "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/socialActions/urn:li:activity:********/comments",
    "body"  => array(
        'actor' => 'urn:li:person:********',
        'object' => 'urn:li:activity:*********',
        'message' => array(
            'text' => 'test..........11'
        ),
        'content' => array()
    ),
);

$lin_access_token = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'lin_access_token', true);

$response1 = wp_remote_post($params1['endpoint'], array(
    'method'      => 'POST',
    'body'        => json_encode($params1['body']),
    'headers'     => array(
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $lin_access_token,
        'x-Restli-Protocol-Version' => '2.0.0',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    ),

));

$responseBody1 = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response1);
$result1 = json_decode($responseBody1, true);
ravi_debug($result1);
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong in this.
I'm getting the following error with try.

```
Array
(
    [serviceErrorCode] => 0
    [message] => Syntax exception in path variables
    [status] => 400
)
```

I have tried this in postman I'm getting the proper output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [socialActions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/network-update-social-actions#create-comment) endpoint require URN of type share or ugcPost instead of activity:

```
POST https://api.linkedin.com/v2/socialActions/{shareUrn|ugcPostUrn}/comments
```

So try to use an URN of format `urn:li:share:{id}` or `urn:li:ugcPost:{id}`.

**NB:** You could use the [Activities API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api#retrieve-activities-and-their-shares) in order to retrieve the share URN, as example:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/activities?ids=urn:li:activity:6252923622642540544
```

will return:

```
{
    "errors": {},
    "results": {
        "urn:li:activity:6252923622642540544": {
            "domainEntity": "urn:li:share:6252923622768377856"
        }
    },
    "statuses": {}
}
```

Comment: Hello @Matteo,
Thank you for replying.
I have tried the same thing in postman using the activity I get the output also.
And I have check-in all post  I don't get the urn share id or urn ugcpost id in API.

Comment: Hi @raviparmar I've updated my answer: you could try with the [activities api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api#retrieve-activities-and-their-shares) to retrieve the share urn